# jQuery - getting error after using onclick event

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below given code is used to create a button in php page.
   After using Onclick event error is throwing
This code giving error like this : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

```
$('#btnCancel').before($('<button onclick = "SubmitAssess(".$this->SLNO->CurrentValue.")">Submit</button>'));
```

Comment: can u show your full code or elaborate your problem? you are creating this button in javascript right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quote nested on a single quote.
It should be as below:

```
$('#btnCancel').before($('<button onclick="AssessmentSubmit(".$this->SLNO->CurrentValue.")">Submit</button>'));
```

On Chrome, you can open the console tab (Ctrl + Shift + I), then paste it to test.